# Alpha vantage API Not working for NSE while the same query is giving output for NYSE stocks

Tags: programming, tick-data

Was trying to pull intraday data with free api from alpha vantage but unable to download it; While At the same time I'm able to download daily OHLC data. 
Also, intraday data query is working for NYSE stocks but not working for NSE or BSE stocks.

I tried lot but not worked for me; also, some time back the same query thrown the result/s and now it is not throwing.

Please help.

I am using R for testing.

If you have any other free data source for live data(NSE feeds) request you to share it.

Answer (score 4):

I tried out Alphavantage a while ago.  I was looking at it as a source of data for US and Canadian stocks.  They use IEX for US stock data.  There are a few other international symbols that do work because they seem to pass-through the request to Yahoo (or other free sources) and return that data back to you. I think they may also use that as a fall-back if their IEX systems stop working too.  However, when there was a common ticker symbol it would only return the US one.  I didn't get a response from my support email.

That they don't acknowledge or detail their data sources or have any way of querying available symbols, or even document which exchanges they cover, should be of concern.

In general, you should not expect to find free live/real-time stock data, as the exchanges charge fees for that.  The IEX data feed is an exception here - but it's not a proper feed - it only shows trades on IEX (under 3% of the market volume).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am aware that, one should not expect for free live data. But, that's what Alpha vantage is advertising.

Comment: Yep - welcome to the world of over-promise and under-deliver when it comes to data.  At least you won't have to ask for a refund.

Comment: I believe to use IEX data you must display on the site that it's the source of data. BATS "one" feed is 99%+ accurate and cheaper than NYSE/NASDAQ.

Comment: If it's BATS data it's 100% accurate for that platform.  It's 0% accurate for every other platform, although highly correlated for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Try NSE:[Stock Symbol] in the URL

Example:

- NSE:TITAN
- NSE:TATASTEEL

Also replace demo apikey with your APIKey

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=**NSE:TITAN**&interval=5min&apikey=**your apikey**&datatype=csv
```

Comment: This does not work for me.